# Is there a possibility to categorize an email with Nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, notifications, nodemailer

I'm working on an web application with ReactJS and Nodejs and I use Nodemailer to send email.
All work fine but, my current issue is that I'm looking for a way to categorize the sent email so that recipients receive it in for example **updates** or **Promotions** category like on this screenshot.[image]

Any help or link to help ?